# Is it possible download library from server in running application?

Tags: android, ios

I'm curious about there is any way to download library from server in running app wheater iOS or Android.
Make it easy, I have a app is able to connect specific server.
In the app, there are 2 buttons with name1, and name2.
So, if I touched name1 button, it automatically download resources and libraries from the server and run. if I touched name2 button, it also download resources and libraries but it is totally diffrent from button name1. As a result, depends on which button I touched, diffrent app is run.
I don't care iOS, Android or web app. If you have any idea it is possible, please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Why dont u already download the library and keep it in your libs folder and then just access them when each of those buttons are clicked.?

Comment: Yes, I'm gonna download and keep it for the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible in Android, but might not be a good idea. You have to be *really* sure that the remote code is safe before executing. Described in more detail [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are describing what app store clients do, so it's possible, but maybe not exactly as you imagine.  You would need to use PackageManager on Android to install the app or library, and your user would have to confirm the install.

Comment: Doesn't care iOS or Android. I found iOS doesn't allow this. Thanks